# What is Rust Self(rhs) and Self(lhs)

Tags: rust

In this code found at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.BitAnd.html:

```rust
use std::ops::BitAnd;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct BooleanVector(Vec<bool>);

impl BitAnd for BooleanVector {
    type Output = Self;

    fn bitand(self, Self(rhs): Self) -> Self::Output {
        let Self(lhs) = self;
        assert_eq!(lhs.len(), rhs.len());
        Self(
            lhs.iter()
                .zip(rhs.iter())
                .map(|(x, y)| *x & *y)
                .collect()
        )
    }
}

let bv1 = BooleanVector(vec![true, true, false, false]);
let bv2 = BooleanVector(vec![true, false, true, false]);
let expected = BooleanVector(vec![true, false, false, false]);
assert_eq!(bv1 & bv2, expected);
```

What is `Self(rhs)` and `Self(lhs)`?
Where does `rhs` and `lhs` come from?

Comment: `lhs` and `rhs` stand for "left-hand side" and "right-hand side". It's what operands of binary operators are usually called.

Comment: It's destructuring the struct to extract the `Vec<bool>`

Comment: The same pattern matching syntax sugar as in `if let Some(foo) = my_option {}`. If it would be `rhs: Self`, you would have to refer to the `Vec<bool>` as `rhs.0` every time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is `Self(rhs)` and `Self(lhs)`?
>
> Where does rhs and lhs come from?

They're patterns. Rust patterns can be faillible, which is how they're generally used (e.g. in `match`, or `if let`). But they can also be *infaillible*.

A basic `let`, or `for`, takes an infaillible pattern as left-hand side. Aside from a trivial binding, this is most commonly encountered with a tuple:

```
let (a, b, c) = ...;
```

`(a, b, c)` is a tuple-pattern, and gets pattern-matched and "unpacked".

This also works with structs in general, and here tuple structs. So

```
let Self(lhs) = self;
```

is just a pattern, which does the reverse operation as

```
let self = Self(lhs);
```

Same with using a pattern as left-hand side in a parameter declaration.

So `lhs` and `rhs` come from pattern-matching the two parameters of the method.

For more, see the book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html#let-statements

Comment: Small nitpick: I suggest changing `Some` into `Self` to better match the code in the question, and to avoid confusions with `Option::Some` (which would make for a fallible pattern).

Comment: Indeed, I actually wrote it reflexively even though I intended to copy the values in the OP. Thanks for the comment.